# mapBubbles is ignoring my limits

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, rworldmap

I'm using mapBubbles from the rworldmap package in R to plot a map of Europe. So far so good, in that I can plot bubbles on the map, label them, etc. However, mapBubbles seems to be ignoring my xlim and ylim values: it will not let me zoom beyond a certain point. Is there any way around this?

```
mapBubbles(dF = df, nameX = "lon", nameY = "lat", nameZSize = "citySizes", nameZColour = c("black"), oceanCol = bcols[10], landCol = bcols[5], borderCol = "darkGrey", symbolSize=0.4, xlim = c(-20,40), ylim = c(30,72), addLegend = FALSE, lwdSymbols=2, fill = FALSE)
```

I would like my map of Europe to have limits: `xlim = c(-20,40), ylim = c(30,72)` but it seems to be giving me something like `xlim = c(-20,45), ylim = c(20,80)` (note the y values).

Comment: It seems, in my limited experimentation, that the limits work best when they are equal in extent.

Comment: Did you find a work through? (Please don't tell no)

Comment: @BhargavRao Not yet!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is two-fold:

1. When axis limits are set in R plots, a buffer is given on either side. This might be to ensure that any points lying exactly at a limit aren't cut in half (which could look really strange depending on how large they are). To fix this for the y-axis, you could set the limits to (31.5, 70.5). *See edit below*
2. It seems that the plot produced by mapBubbles has set dimensions. Therefore, the percent that you're zooming in by has to be the same for both the x- and y-axes. In order to zoom in as closely as you'd like for the x-axis, you'd end up zooming in too far on the y-axis.

Solution: If you really want to remove the excess, you can add some white rectangles to the edges of the plot. This would work for your example after changing the y limits to those shown in problem 1 above (or at least it does on my computer):

```
rect(-35, 29, -20, 73, col = "white", border = NA)
rect(40, 29, 55, 73, col = "white", border = NA)
```

---

Edit:
I found a better solution for the extra buffer that R adds to the axis limits. Rather than change the coordinates for the y-axis from c(30, 72) to c(31.5, 70.5), you can simply change the graphical parameters. Using `par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")` will remove that buffer (which apparently is 4%, for anyone who's wondering). The code for the rectangles doesn't need to be changed.